# Which is more accurate: Euler's method or modified Euler's method?

Tags: computational-physics, mathematics, error-analysis, approximations, algorithms

I was solving a differential equation, the equation being,
$$\frac{dv}{dt} = g-\frac{c_d}{m}v^2,$$
which can be solved analytically to give
$$v = \sqrt{\frac{mg}{c_d}}\left(\frac{e^{2t\sqrt{\frac{c_dg}{m}}}-1}{e^{2t\sqrt{\frac{c_dg}{m}}}+1}\right)$$

Say, I have been given, $m = 68.1$ kg, $c_d = 0.25$ kg/m and $g=9.8$ m/s$^2$. I was calculating the value of $v$ at $t = 10$ s by a step increment of $h = 1$ s using the [modified Euler's method](https://math.iitm.ac.in/public_html/sryedida/caimna/ode/euler/ie.html). This involves calculating the predicting value, like [Euler's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method). I found that values calculated by Euler's method were more accurate than that of the modified Euler's method at the later values of $t$.

[image]

So I am unsure which is more accurate and under what conditions one is more accurate. And are there any errors in what I have done?